# Limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n \cdot\ln(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n)$

Tags: limits, radicals

How should this limit be solved ?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \ln(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n)$$

I've tried to multiply and at the same time divide $\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n$ by $\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}+n$, and then make $n$ as the power of $\frac {2n+5}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}+n}$. But I got stuck.  I dont think it was the best idea.

Comment: Do you know L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes its is used in cases of nedetermination as 0/0 or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: You have $\infty\times0$, which can be easily manipulated into $\frac00$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \ln (\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \ln (\sqrt{(n+1)^2+4}-n) $$
so we change variable: $a= n+1 \to \infty $ to get
$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} (a-1) \cdot \ln (\sqrt{a^2+4}-a+1) $$
But we know that for $a \to \infty $, for a product $ (a-1)$ behaves as $a$ and that $ \sqrt{a^2+4} $ behaves as $ a + \frac{2}{a} $ and so our limit becomes
$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} a \cdot \ln (a+\frac{2}{a}-a+1) $$ which simplifies to
$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} a \cdot \ln (1+\frac{2}{a}) $$
and since, for small $x$, one has $ \ln(1+x) = x $, the limit becomes
$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} a \cdot \frac{2}{a} = 2 $$

Comment: Furthermore, using a calculator to determine the value of the expression for n=1000 gives a value of 1.996, which shows the expression tending to 2...

Comment: @Assaultuous2 Sorry, may be its a stupid question, but can you please explain me, why $\sqrt{a^2+4}$ behaves as $a+\frac{2}{a}$?

Comment: No, its not a stupid question... Try it yourself: square a+2/a and see what you get... if you still dont see it, ask me again

Comment: If I square a+2/2 I get that the limit to $\infty$ is 1...

Comment: The square of a+2/a is a^2+4+4/a^2, which is what is inside your root, just off by a very tiny value of order 1/a^2.

Comment: Thank you, and the last one> what does it mean that for small x one has ln(1+x)=x?

Comment: It means that for $x \to 0$ $\log (1+x)$ grows at roughly the rate of $x$. You can get it using Taylor series.

Comment: More precisely: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$ (also written as $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\to0$).

Comment: @ John Green: Are you satisfied with the explanations, or are you still confused about some things?

Comment: @Assaultous2 I am still confused about  a+2/a and a^2+4a+4/a^2. Why are these two similar? Their limits to infinity are different: (a^2+4a+4)/a^2 has the limit 1 but $lim_{n\to \infty}{n^2+4}$ is $\infty$.